# What's the reading order for Age of Apocalypse?

Tags: marvel, x-men, suggested-order

I've been looking around and found many many conflicting topics. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

There's an extensive [reading order guide](http://www.comicbookherald.com/the-complete-marvel-reading-order-guide/age-of-apocalypse-reading-order/) on ComicBookHerald.

The nub of their suggestion is that you completely avoid [Book One](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785117148) of the [collected series](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785117148). It's very poorly reviewed on Amazon and near-universally derided as a...

> **"...selection of unimportant side stories that serves as a poor
>   introduction to this fan favorite alternate universe storyline"**